# media9 and remote web image

Tags: diagrams, media9

Hi guys I need to put a remote image on a pdf. Such that if the remote picture changes then
also the pdf when opened changes its content.
I am trying to use media9 package but I am getting nowhere.
Could you please show me an example which works?

Thanks.

Comment: You need a an image viewer swf app. This is embedded with `media9` and has to be configured to load the remote image. You can program such an app using Apache Flex.